# Get variables from Swift file with Native Modules for React Native?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, react-native, macros

I have **React Native** app and I need to implement native modules on **IOS** with **RCT_EXTERN_METHOD** macros. 
My steps:

1. Created Settings.swift file in **XCode**.
2. Created Bridging - Header.
3. Created Settings.m file in **XCode**.
4. Declared Class component and inside variable and function in Settings.swift file in **Xcode**.
5. Registered functions in Settings.m file with **RCT_EXTERN_METHOD** macros in XCode.
6. Imported **Native Modules** and used it in **React Native** project.

I need to use variables from my swift file like state in my React Native project and manage it with declared function from **Swift** file. When i call the function it works, but i can not get variables from **Native Modules** like NativeModules.Settings.getSwitchGeneralTagLog
i get undefined. Can you tell me please how can i get variable from Native Module? And is it good way to use it for state? Which the best way to manage state in **Swift**?

Settings.swift:

```
import Foundation

@objc(Settings)
class Settings: NSObject {


  private var generalTagLog = false

  @objc
  func getSwitchGeneralTagLog() -> Bool {
    return generalTagLog
  }

  @objc
  func switchGeneralTagLog() -> Bool {
    return generalTagLog ? false : true
  }


  @objc
  static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
    return true
  }
}
```

Settings.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(Settings, NSObject)
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(switchGeneralTagLog)

@end
```

Comment: You can  create a function to return variables from the Swift.

Comment: I have already tried with function and got the error: Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `function` supplied to `Switch`, expected `boolean`.

Comment: Please show me the part where you made the function and the part where you called it.

Comment: Made - https://codeshare.io/ad9kxK, call - https://codeshare.io/5ol4zb

Comment: The two codes are the same.

Comment: Sorry)) check it again please!

Comment: @jocoders Did you solve this problem? I'm currently having the same issue.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://carminedimascio.com/2016/01/create-a-react-native-custom-swift-component/

Answer (score 0):

I am going to focus on one function and you can extend it based on that

Settings.m

```
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(getSwitchGeneralTagLog:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)promise rejector: (RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
```

In the below scenario, we are not processing any exception

Settings.swift

```swift
 @objc func getSwitchGeneralTagLog(_ promise: RCTPromiseResolveBlock, rejector reject: RCTPromiseRejectBlock) {

    var isSwitch = false 

     // figure out what need to be done for the flag 

    promise(isSwitch)
  }
```

in your RN Accept you can extract the result from promise and use it.

Comment: This is involving a promise. I want to know how to call a function and return a result synchronously.

Comment: As JS is single threaded, it is better to follow this approach.  Use `await` on the JS layer to ensure that the values are returned before moving forward with the next step on the JS layer

Comment: That's how I did implement it. However I wanted to know how I could do it synchronously.

Comment: @HarveyConnor did you find the answer? I am also want to it synchronously. 
But if do this it synchronously - return value is undefined in js, in swift value - displays ok

Comment: @HarveyConnor
I found the answer. RN Doc says
"The return type of bridge methods is always void. React Native bridge is asynchronous, so the only way to pass a result to JavaScript is by using callbacks or emitting events (see below)."